# Friends and Templates C++

Tags: c++, templates, friend

There are many threads in the forum about the Friends and Templates. I specially checked this one here:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.16

But a little confused about one paragraph here:

> The snag happens when the compiler sees the friend lines way up in the
>   class definition proper. At that moment it does not yet know the
>   friend functions are themselves templates; it assumes they are
>   non-templates like this:

```
Foo<int> operator+ (const Foo<int>& lhs, const Foo<int>& rhs)
{ ... }

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const Foo<int>& x)
{ ... }
```

I must confess that i don't know much about compiler technology. What I am confused here is that why the statement inside the class like this one is not sufficient to say the function operator+ is a template function?:

```
friend Foo<T> operator+ (const Foo<T>& lhs, const Foo<T>& rhs);
```

It has a template parameter T and triangle brackets...
I am trying to think what other type it can be other than template function. but can not get my minds through that.

I am also confused on the assumption compiler make. Why does it specific chose type < int >? Why does compile make this assumption but not a template function - which seems more reasonable to me.

Thanks a lot,

Chen

Comment: you might find this useful although it's not really an answer to your question: http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/templates.html#fqa-35.16

Comment: It chooses `<int>` because in this example, the instantiation is on `T == int`: `Foo<int> lhs(1);`

Comment: Thanks DyP. I overlooked the main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you declare friend function in class, which is template (declared before), you have to signal compiler that, declared function is template by placing empty angle brackets or by qualifying it for e.g:

http://ideone.com/kmIfc

If you don't do that either then declared friend function is supposed as declaration of new function if there is no previous declared non-template function.

http://ideone.com/woIgn

Comment: Standard, 14.5.3/1 point 1 and 3 on the interpretation of template friend declarations: 1) the version with <>, that is, a template-id. 3) the version where you have specialized the function template yourself (before the friend declaration). Point 4 in the list allows declaration of a new non-template [!] function.